# Objects are not valid as a React child - is my JSON data bad?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am aware this has been asked several times on Stack Overflow, but other solutions don't seem to work for me.

I am trying to access the notifications in this JSON file.

My JSON file: https://dinkyapp.000webhostapp.com/db.json

Is my JSON file poorly structured? I know it's pretty big. In the world outside of React, the JSON file works fine. But in React, it's unworkable, no matter if I parse, convert to arrays etc. Should I make multiple smaller files instead?

In my example, I'm trying to access the notifications and return them in the JSX.

I get the error, 'Objects are not valid as a React child'.
I also get notifs.map is not a function. Presumably this is because the data being pulled through is not in an array format.

My component code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const GetData = () => {
 
    
    let [notifs, setNotifs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('db.json').then((res) => {
        var data = res.data.clients.clientID_1.notifications;
        setNotifs(data);
        

      });
    }, []);

    const getIDs = 
        notifs.map(item => {
            return (
            <p key={notifs.reqID}>{notifs.text}</p>
            )
        })
    

    return <div>{getIDs}</div>;
    };

    export default GetData;
```

I'm nearly about to switch back to Vanilla JS as I have tried so many ways. But I think it may be my JSON data being poor. If anyone could please advise?

Many thanks

Comment: you are trying to use `notifs` as both an array when you map and an object when you use `. notation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If look at https://dinkyapp.000webhostapp.com/db.json `res.data.clients.clientID_1.notifications` it is object like:

```
const notifs = {
    userID_1: [
        {
            timestamp: 1613777053000,
            reqID: 100012,
            seen: true,
            text: 'Aaron F accepted your shift swap',
        },
    ],
    userID_2: [
        {
            timestamp: 1614676200000,
            reqID: 199290,
            seen: true,
            text: 'Sean W approved your Annual Leave request',
        },
        {
            timestamp: 1610719942000,
            reqID: 184828,
            seen: true,
            text: 'Sean W approved your Annual Leave request',
        },
    ],
};
```

Not array, so you need work with it as an object, example:

```
const getIDs = Object.keys(notifs).map(key => {
    return (
        <p key={key}>
            From {key}
            {notifs[key].map(n => (
                <p key={n.reqID}>{n.text}</p>
            ))}
        </p>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are trying to map over objects, for simplify your JSON could be

```
"notifications": [
   {
     "user_id": 1 // move user id here
     "timestamp": 1613777053000,
     "reqID": 100012,
     "seen": true,
     "text": "Aaron F accepted your shift swap"
   },
   {
     "user_id": 2, // move user id here
     "timestamp": 1613777053000,
     "reqID": 100012,
     "seen": true,
     "text": "Aaron F accepted your shift swap"
}]
```

then you now map safely

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
<p key={item.reqID}>{item.text}</p>
```